# Sending a dm when banning someone discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have a discord spam kick bot and i want to send a private message when you get banned. i tried this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message, ctx):
    counter = 0
    with open("spam_detect.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            if lines.strip("\n") == str(message.author.id):
                counter += 1

        file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)}\n")
        if counter > 4 and not message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            await message.guild.ban(message.author, reason="Spammer")
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author} kicked for spam.")
         ***ctx.author.send(message.author, "You were kicked for spam. You can rejoin in`60`seconds")***
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
            await message.guild.unban(message.author)
            print(f"{message.author} kicked for spam.")
```

But it doesn't work `TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'`

The problem is that it also broke the rest of the code..so is not working at all now.

Any ideas on how can i send a dm ***to the persson who got banned*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `ctx` parameter since it's not passed when `on_message` is called, and instead of `ctx.author.send()` use `message.author.send()`. If you really want to use `ctx` in `on_message`, because you need it for other parts of your code that you haven't shown here because it's irrelevant for the question, add `ctx = await bot.get_context(message)` at the top of `on_message`

---

References:

- [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message)
- [get_context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context)

Comment: I get this error now: `TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`..could this be because of the `(message.author,` ?

Comment: You just have to use `message.author.send("You were kicked for spam. You can rejoin in 60 seconds")` @MihaiCristian